# timer implementation in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

I had written following code for implementing a timer in JS. But the issue is, for the subsequent recursive calls, the method throws reference error for timeChkSplitTime. How does it happen as its being passed in `settimeout()`.
Also, later I used the easy timer js lib for this. If possible, pls provide an idea to configure the timer for minutes and seconds alone.

```
function timeChkold(timeChkSplitTime) {
    var min = timeChkSplitTime[0], sec = timeChkSplitTime[1];
    if (!(timeChkSplitTime[0]==0 && splitTime[1]==0)) {
        var strSec, strMin = "0"+min.toString();
        if (sec < 10) strSec = "0"+ sec.toString();
        else strSec = sec.toString();
        $(".timer-btn time").html(strMin+":"+strSec);
        timeChkSplitTime[0]=0;
        if (sec > 0) timeChkSplitTime[1]--;
        else timeChkSplitTime[1] = 59;
        setTimeout( "timeChk(timeChkSplitTime);", 1000);
    }
    else {
        var startBtn = $(".start-btn");
        startBtn.html("Start");
        startBtn.css( {
            "border": "1px solid #56B68B",
            "background": "#56B68B",
        });
        var startTime = "01:00";
        $(".timer-btn time").html(startTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: the question is a little bit unclear to me. you want a timer? or a countdown? timer starts from 00:00 and counts up. countdown the other way around.

Comment: its for a countdown timer

Comment: i added a code snippet for you that should solve your issue completely.

Answer (score 0):

Variables aren't parsed through strings, on the line with the code:

```
setTimeout( "timeChk(timeChkSplitTime);", 1000);
```

It's literally reading the parameter as the value as the text `timeChkSplitTime` and not the value of the variable `timeChkSplitTime`. Other than using a string use a function for `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout( timeChk(timeChkSplitTime), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout( "timeChk(timeChkSplitTime);", 1000);
```

should be

```
setTimeout( timeChk(timeChkSplitTime), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is a little bit of a spaghetti code. you should seperate your code logic from the view. split them into functions. and most importantly, using setTimeout is not efficient in this case.

```js
var CountdownTimer = function(startTime) {
  var timeInSeconds = this.stringToSeconds(startTime);
  this.original = timeInSeconds;
  this.time = timeInSeconds;
  this.running = false;
}

CountdownTimer.prototype.start = function(callback) {
  this.running = true;
  this.interval = setInterval(function() {
      if(this.time < 1) {
        this.running = false;
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      } else {
        this.time -= 1;
        callback();
      }
  }.bind(this), 1000);
}

CountdownTimer.prototype.pause = function() {
  if(this.running) {
    this.running = false;
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
CountdownTimer.prototype.restart = function() {
  this.time = this.original;
}

CountdownTimer.prototype.stringToSeconds = function(timeSting) {
  var timeArray = timeSting.split(':');
  var minutes = parseInt(timeArray[0], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timeArray[1], 10);
  var totalSeconds = (minutes*60) + seconds;
  return totalSeconds;
}
CountdownTimer.prototype.secondsToStrings = function(timeNumber) {
  finalString = '';
  var minutes = parseInt(timeNumber/60, 10);
  var seconds = timeNumber - (minutes*60);
  var minStr = String(minutes);
  var secStr = String(seconds);
  if(minutes < 10) minStr = "0" + minStr;
  if(seconds < 10) secStr = "0" + secStr;
  return minStr + ":" + secStr;
}
```

to run this code you can add the following

```
var countdownTest = new CountdownTimer("01:15");
countdownTest.start(onEachTick);

function onEachTick() {
  var time = countdownTest.secondsToStrings(countdownTest.time);
  console.log(time)
}
```

you can write your custom code in the onEachTick funciton.
you can check if the timer is running by typing countdownTest.running.

you can also restart and pause the timer. now you can customize your views however you want.